# How to debug #REF in Excel Index function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have two Excel Workbooks:

- Data.xlsx
- Report.xlsx

I want to reference Data.xlsx from Report.xlsx and I reference using the following formula:

```
=INDEX('[Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$7:$F$33,2,6)
```

It works fine. However if I try to reference the next cell I get a #REF error.

```
=INDEX('[Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$7:$F$33,2,7)
```

It's behaving like I'm querying outside the bounds of the range.
How can I debug this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you ARE outside the bounds of the range.

```
A B C D E F G
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

...but you are going to the 7th column... just change it to

```
=INDEX('[Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$7:$G$33,2,7)
```